# Change project file name in Xcode 10

Tags: rename, project, xcode10

I am trying to change a Project name in Xcode 10 and I have tried all the suggested methods I could find;

1. Rename project
2. Rename the Scheme
3. Rename the folder with your assets
4. Rename the Build plist data

I do all the above steps and the project complies and builds with out issues.

When I load the app on a iPhone, it crashed when I select a specific screen and I get the following errors;

```
2019-07-29 17:56:13.315622-0400 SkeetLauncher_RevA[736:163909] Unknown class _TtC14SKEET_LAUNCHER13launchButtons in Interface Builder file.
2019-07-29 17:56:13.363768-0400 SkeetLauncher_RevA[736:163909] [Graphics] UIColor created with component values far outside the expected range. Set a breakpoint on UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents to debug. This message will only be logged once.
2019-07-29 17:56:13.372489-0400 SkeetLauncher_RevA[736:163909] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x101d01910> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key DELAY.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18f237ea0 0x18e409a40 0x18f15197c 0x18fbe320c 0x1bbce65e4 0x1bbf5fa5c 0x18f121748 0x1bbf5c6cc 0x1bbced25c 0x1bbcedc08 0x1bbceded0 0x1bbcee63c 0x1bbc46e28 0x1bbc5b8e8 0x1bbc5cdbc 0x1bbc3efac 0x1bc75aea4 0x19382ac70 0x19382fc00 0x19378e718 0x1937bd04c 0x1937bdeb4 0x18f1c77a8 0x18f1c243c 0x18f1c29dc 0x18f1c21cc 0x191439584 0x1bc2b5054 0x100c453f4 0x18ec82bb4)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.
```

The project compiles and runs fine before I do the rename process.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the storyboard and reenter all the view controller class names.

Comment: Excellent! I want to hear about what the right direction was. Note that it is legal to answer your own question (in the Answer field).

Answer (score 0):

That didn't work but it pointed me in the right direction, Thanks
I had to change the "Module" for "Custom Class" in identity inspector. I guess the "Change Project Name" process didn't automatically do it for all the view controllers. Attached is picture for clarification.
[MODULE in Identity Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKCpm.png)

Comment: OK but that is my answer, repeated. When you change the view controller class name and hit Return, the module name is changed automatically. That is _why_ I told you to change the view controller class name.

Comment: Yes, You are correct but I misunderstood you first message and changed the names on the "Identity and Type" screen not the "Custom Class" screen; every day is a learning process